# Check string exist in array dart / flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

i have array like this

```
var data = [manggo, lemon, watermelon, guava];
```

I want to display watermelon when I pass the string "water", how do I do that?
when i use contains, it will return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```
 void main() {
  
 List<String> data = ["manggo", "lemon", "watermelon", "guava"];
  
 List<String> searchData(String text){
    if(text.isEmpty){
      return data;
    }
    return data.where((element) => element.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())).toList();
  }
  
  print(searchData("wa"));
  print(searchData("g"));
  print(searchData("gu"));
}
```

output:

```
[watermelon]
[manggo, guava]
[guava]
```

Answer (score 3):

how about this:

```
void main() {
 var data = ["manggo", "lemon", "watermelon", "guava"];

print(data.where((e)=> e.contains("water")).toList());
}
```

[image]